# Executing Cron Job CentOS7 PHP 7.1

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to execute cron jobs but none seem to work, it's several different ones, different files, yet none work.

I have tried many variations of the php path and the php file path is correct.
`/usr/bin/php /home/xxx/public_html/vendors/notifywhenavailable/sendMails.php`

This is one of four PHP files, none seem to execute.

My latest update via email for the cron is Status: 301 Moved Permanently, however all PHP file locations are correct. I have tried usr/bin/php usr/local/bin/php I have tried /usr/local/bin/ea-php71 - literally nothing will execute these.

Comment: Please show your cron entry.

Comment: shouldn't this /home/xxx/public_html be /var/www/public_html

Comment: And what happens when you run the above commands in your terminal ? Do you see any output ? Are there any errors in the PHP error log ?